# Magento2 What is the difference between uiCollection and uiComponent

Tags: magento2, javascript, uicomponent, requirejs

Refer to the file -

```
vendor\magento\module-ui\view\base\requirejs-config.js
```

You will see code in `map` like -

```
uiCollection:   'Magento_Ui/js/lib/core/collection',
uiComponent:    'Magento_Ui/js/lib/core/collection',
```

What is the difference between these two and how are they mapped?

Answer (score 2):

My take on this is a UI component is the name given to a UI element or collection of elements, such as a form, button, modal etc.

And the UI Collection is the Javascript you use to build a UI component (or collection of them).

I'm not too sure why there are two files mapped to the same file, this doesn't sound great practice as it promotes inconsistency.

More info can be found in the docs:

- https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/ui_comp_guide/concepts/ui_comp_uicollection_concept.html
- https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/ui_comp_guide/bk-ui_comps.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have reviewed the links shared, all I was concerned about why the name is same. And how to use this.